# Counting lines in a Input text file c++

Tags: c++

I've been looking for a concise answer to my question. It seems to be a very common issue but I haven't seen anyone that has asked the question in a tightly focused way nor have I found an appropriate answer.

I'm just trying to find out how many lines are in a particular file using the filename.eof() command. Like so:

```
ifstream InFile;
InFile.open("Input.txt")    
int counter=0;
while(!InFile.eof())
  counter++;
```

I've been finding that sometimes the condition works when using it for other things but not always. I don't understand what the difference is and I don't know why. Can anyone explain? Help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: That loop will spin *forever*. You never read anything. Maybe try *reading* something.

Comment: @WhozCraig Would it continue spinning if I pulled the plug?

Comment: @GillBates that all depends on the perpetual efficiency of your UPS =P